# SQL Query with Multiple Like Clauses

Tags: sql, database

I would like to create a SQL query, which does the following..
 - I have a few parameters, for instance like "John","Smith"
 - Now I have a articles tables with a content column, which I would like to be searched
 - Now, How can I find out the rows in the articles table, which has the any one of those values("John","Smith")

I cannot use content LIKE "%john% or content LIKE "%smith%", as there could be any number of incoming parameters.

Can you guys please tell me a way to do this....
Thanks

Comment: How are you constructing the query? There's no reason why you couldn't use multiple `LIKE` statements by building the query dynamically.

Comment: Which SQL Database?  Oracle, MySQL, Postgress, Access?  The answer might depend on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered full-text search?

Comment: This is why I commented above about "which database" -- I knew someone would answer this way.

Answer (score 1):

While HLGEM's solution is ideal, if full-text search is not possible, you could construct a regular expression that you could test only once per row.  How exactly you do that depends on the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This depends a lot on the DBMS you're using. Generally - if you don't want to use full-text search - you can almost always use regular expressions to achive this goal. For MySQL see [this manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) - they even have example answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

If full text search is overkill, consider putting the parameters in a table and use `LIKE in the`JOIN` condition e.g.

```
SELECT * -- column list in production code
  FROM Entities AS E1
       INNER JOIN Params AS P1
          ON E1.entity_name LIKE '%' + P1.param + '%';
```